# Получение значений из списка словарей

Tags: python, словарь

Есть вот такой код.

```
info = client.get_margin_account()
temp = info['userAssets']
```

Вывод: список словарей.

```
[{'asset': 'MATIC', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '0'}, {'asset': 'YFII', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '0'}, {'asset': 'VET', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '0'}, {'asset': 'CRV', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '0'}, {'asset': 'GRT', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '0'}, {'asset': 'USDT', 'free': '60.40787499', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '60.40787499'}, {'asset': 'SUSHI', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '0'}, {'asset': 'RVN', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '0'}]
```

Мне нужно обратиться к элементу вложенного словаря в разделе USDT. Получить данные, что `'asset': 'USDT'`
и `'free': '60.40787499'`
Как это сделать? Пытался через цикл `for`, но не понимаю, как обозначить элемент списка. Обращаться к нему по индексу, например`info['userAssets'][6]` не вариант, так как валюта может добавиться и индекс собьется. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении двигаться.

Спасибо за подсказки!

Comment: Можно, конечно, написать костыли и придумать, что по обращению к элементу индекса проверять равняется ли`'asset' == 'USDT'` и если нет, дальше перебирать индексы, но мне кажется есть более элегантный способ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l = [
    {'asset': 'MATIC', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '0'}, 
    {'asset': 'YFII', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '0'}, 
    {'asset': 'VET', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '0'}, 
    {'asset': 'CRV', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '0'}, 
    {'asset': 'GRT', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '0'}, 
    {'asset': 'USDT', 'free': '60.40787499', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '60.40787499'}, 
    {'asset': 'SUSHI', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '0'}, 
    {'asset': 'RVN', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '0'}
]

for x in l:
     if x["asset"] == "USDT":
            print(x["free"])
```

> 60.40787499

Comment: Правильно понимаю, что каждый словарь был пронумерован через `x`? Затем был задан цикл и уже обращение к элементу каждого словаря?

Comment: х в данном случае - это каждый объект итератора (вашего списка). то есть, каждый словарь последовательно.

Comment: Спасибо преогромное!

Comment: Понятно. То есть фактически у разработчиков не было другого варианта создания вложенного словаря. Только через список, который находится в другом словаре. Все предельно ясно! Спасибо

Comment: И еще вопрос возник. Он те такой важный, но может знаете. Периодически принтую результат, чтобы убедиться в правильности структуры и работы с ней. Иногда попадаются огромные размеры словарей. При выводе через terminal VS, часто начало вывода обрезается. Расширение Arepl частично снимает вопрос, но все же? Почему так происходит и есть ли стандартные способы получить весь вывод от начала и до конца?

Comment: Если вам для дебага требуется просматривать объемы данных, то я бы советовал либо писать в файл встроенными способами, либо использовать функционал модуля logger (тоже в файл, например).

Comment: Скорее для просмотра структуры данных. Просто, если бы обрезали конец вывода, то фиг с ним. А так я даже не могу понять начальную структуру и следовательно не могу понять, к кому сначала обращаться.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с использованием `Pandas`. Вдруг потом будет нужно ещё какие-то значения дёргать, а через `Pandas` это бывает удобно:

```
import pandas as pd

l = [
    {'asset': 'MATIC', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '0'}, 
    {'asset': 'YFII', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '0'}, 
    {'asset': 'VET', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '0'}, 
    {'asset': 'CRV', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '0'}, 
    {'asset': 'GRT', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '0'}, 
    {'asset': 'USDT', 'free': '60.40787499', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '60.40787499'}, 
    {'asset': 'SUSHI', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '0'}, 
    {'asset': 'RVN', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0', 'borrowed': '0', 'interest': '0', 'netAsset': '0'}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(l)
print(df.loc[df.asset == "USDT", 'free'].values)
```

Вывод:

```
['60.40787499']
```

Comment: Да, как вариант. А есть весомые причины использовать именно такую библиотеку?  В чем ее преимущество?

Comment: Часто вижу ее в требованиях по устройству на работу. Но глубоко не вникал, так как работу не ищу.

Comment: @Antony `Pandas` очень удобна для работы с табличными данными и она в общем не сложная, очень рекомендую изучить. И как в данном примере она очень много видов данных умеет сама распознать как табличку.